# C# - Drawstring is not removing previous drawn string on Drawing

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a software, In which there is a drawing which have multiple horizontal lines with corresponding value displayed below each line. All values are displayed with the help of `for` loop.

```
g.DrawString(GetValue(i), ObjectFont.TextFont, ObjectFont.TextBrush.GetBrush(), rectSplit.Location); //g is Graphics
```

When I resize the size of the drawing, those values gets updated accordingly.

```
if (/* resize condition */)
{
rectsplit.X = someValue; // Will give new X position to display.
g.DrawString(GetValue(i), ObjectFont.TextFont, ObjectFont.TextBrush.GetBrush(), rectSplit.Location);
}
```

Now, the problem here is - **When new values are drawn, the old values aren't removed instantly**.

Here are Images for better understanding  the issue -

**Image without any Issue -**

[image: Image without any Issue.]

**Image with Issue when resized -**

[image: Image with Issue when resized]

Comment: a) I don#t really see the issue. b) we don't see the creation of `g`. c) we don't see where the code is called. - Try either graphics.clear(Color.TransparentOrMaybeWhite) or controlRefresh()

Comment: The snippets are too lame to see the bug.  But DrawString can only ever work correctly when it draws on top of a properly painted background.  That didn't happen so crystal ball says that this code is not called by the Paint event.  Rubbing it a bit more it says "another CreateGraphics bug".

Answer (score 2):

This is the right behaviour, when you draw a string this becomes part of the image. You could keep a copy of the plain image and then redraw the strings at correct positions on resize event